# Why would being called "Mr. Yellow" be undesirable?

Tags: plot-explanation, reservoir-dogs

In Reservoir Dogs (1992), Joe assigns code names to a group of people: Mr. Brown, Mr. White, Mr. Blonde, Mr. Blue, Mr. Orange, and Mr. Pink. One person questions why they were assigned the name
“Mr. Pink” and Joe responds with an offensive remark. Mr. Pink asks why they can’t
choose their own code names and Joe explains that it has caused problems in the past.
Joe insists on choosing the code names and tells Mr. Pink to be grateful they were
not assigned “Mr. Yellow.”:

> Joe:  You're Mr Pink. Be thankful you're not **Mr Yellow**.

Why would being called "Mr. Yellow" be undesirable?

Comment: That would just be a confusion with Mr. Blonde, I guess.

Comment: It's interesting how quickly words -- and even concepts -- fall out of cultural favor.  Up through the 1970s, it was common to point out when a man or boy was a coward by calling him "yellow" or "a yellow belly".  Now ***maybe*** it has it's roots in the fact that East Asians were the "yellow races", but it certainly never occurred to us that we were equating cowards with Chinese or Japanese.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

"Yellow" is slang for being cowardly.

e.g. per [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=yellow)

> To be cowardly, or a pussy

Maybe [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/231534?rskey=J8kkgF&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) is a better place to see this meaning as Urban Dictionary seems a bit volatile...

> [3] b. colloquial (originally U.S.). Lacking in courage; faint-hearted; cowardly.

Comment: I would remove the Urban Dictionary reference to avoid ridicule.

Comment: I actually think the Urban Dictionary version give a better sense of what the characters in this movie probably think.

Comment: The problem with UD is that it's based on voting, so the "top" answer can change over time. Still, you have a valid point.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Well, the movie was made before Urban Dictionary existed, and UD has lots of very niche internet slang which most people wouldn't know. The regular old Cambridge dictionary lists "Yellow-Bellied" and gives "Yellow" as a synonym.

Comment: Alternately, yellow is also an old slang term for people of asian heritage - see Bruce Springsteens song "Born in the USA".

Comment: In the same scene, shortly after "be thankful you're not Mr. Yellow", the name "Mr. Brown" is equated with "Mr. Shit", and "Mr. Piss" is mentioned, so perhaps there's the additional meaning of yellow being the colour if urine. Just a thought.

Comment: One other famous use in a movie comes to mind in Monty Python's Holy Grail: https://youtu.be/ZmInkxbvlCs?t=164

Comment: @AllanMills  the association wtih beople of Asian heritage  seems unlikely.  In the same scene it is noted that if people chose their own code names "you get five guys fighting over who is Mr. Black"  That's nothing to do with race, and everything to do with "black" representing "criminal, villainous, evil, heartless" - all the things these gangsters aspire to.

Comment: @JamesK black is just cool

Comment: @slingeraap I associate the usage with Westerns, so it's a slight surprise to hear Python use it.